# Heap Dump shows many instances of java.lang.Thread

Tags: memory-leaks, heap-memory, jboss5.x, heap-dump, rhel6

I'm analyzing java application deployed in Jboss 5.1 container in RHEL 6.

Ηeap dump of my application, when analyzed through Eclipse Mat, suggests that about 83% of the heap memory is occupied by `java.land.Thread` instance. Can you please help me understand if this signifies a memory leak in the application?

Result from Eclipse MAT:

```
Problem Suspect 1

4,184 instances of "java.lang.Thread", loaded by "<system class loader>" occupy 2,821,477,400 (83.40%) bytes. 

Keywords  
java.lang.Thread
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to indent your code sample by 4 spaces and also add backticks to inline code so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in to provide any additional detail that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!